# submit php form with array values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have form in html like this:
[image]

It has multiple values. I want to submit those values with validation. For example, If somebody enter the value of ad length then he must fill all other fields for that particular row. After that I want to submit the form and store all correct values (I mean, there won't be any conflicts in row.) in to the database.

HTML CODE:

```
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
            <tr>
              <th>Ad Length</th>
              <th>Ad Type</th>
              <th>Ad Location</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                  <select name="ad_length[]" id="">
              </td>
            </tr>
```

And so on for other elements...

This is myPHP code:

```
 $ad_length = $_POST['ad_length'];
            $ad_type = $_POST['ad_type'];
            $ad_location = $_POST['ad_location'];
            $ad_price = $_POST['ad_price'];
            foreach($ad_length as $al){
                print_r($al." , ");
            }
```

But, I think, I am doing wrong somewhere?
What will be the perfect solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: can you post the html of one line?

Comment: Make sure you assign names to each tr below thead.

Comment: are you against the use of javascript? bucause usin just html, you would validate eavrything filled, or noo valdation, and php only validates after the data has been submitted

Answer (score 0):

This should be a place to start.

```
<?php

 if(isset($ad_length)){
    if(!isset($ad_type)){
        echo 'Please enter type of advert'
    }         
    elseif{
        ...
    } 
    else{
        /* Insert into database */
    }
}

?>
```